# Draw 2D trail of ship. XNA

Tags: c#, xna, draw, xna-4.0, bezier

I've been looking for a solution to this for some time now and already have many elements to work with but not really how to piece them together.

Objective: Draw a trail for the player's ship.

So far: Since the ship's direction is unpredictable I have only the previous positions of the player's ship to work with. To draw the trail I could simply draw a pixel (or a texture) at the previous position of the player but this is memory expensive and it doesn't draw curves, it won't achieve a pleasing to the eye curved effect.

I've been looking into Beziers Paths and Cathmull Rom for solutions.

Now I can get the control points for a given point, then from 2 points and 2 control points calculate a curve, from here I make an array of VertexPositionColor with a distance between points to make a triangleStrip from the curve.

These are the main functions I have so far:

```
        public Vector2[] GetControlPoints(Vector2 p0, Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, float tension = 0.5f)
        {
            // get length of lines [p0-p1] and [p1-p2]
            float d01 = Vector2.Distance(p0, p1);
            float d12 = Vector2.Distance(p1, p2);
            // calculate scaling factors as fractions of total
            float sa = tension * d01 / (d01 + d12);
            float sb = tension * d12 / (d01 + d12);
            // left control point
            float c1x = p1.X - sa * (p2.X - p0.X);
            float c1y = p1.Y - sa * (p2.Y - p0.Y);
            // right control point
            float c2x = p1.X + sb * (p2.X - p0.X);
            float c2y = p1.Y + sb * (p2.Y - p0.Y);
            return new Vector2[] {new Vector2(c1x, c1y), new Vector2(c2x, c2y) };
        }

         // Given 2 points and 2 control points
        public static VertexPositionColor[] bezierCurve(Vector2 start, Vector2 end, Vector2 c1, Vector2 c2)
        {
            VertexPositionColor[] points = new VertexPositionColor[SUBDIVISIONS + 2];

            float fraction;

            for (int i = 0; i < SUBDIVISIONS + 2; i++)
            {
                fraction = i * (1f / (float)SUBDIVISIONS);
                points[i] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3((float)((start.X * Math.Pow((1 - fraction), 3))
                    +(c1.X * 3 * fraction * Math.Pow(1-fraction, 2))
                    +(c2.X * 3 * Math.Pow(fraction,2) * (1-fraction))
                    +(end.X * Math.Pow(fraction,3))),

                    (float)((start.Y * Math.Pow((1 - fraction), 3))
                    + (c1.Y * 3 * fraction * Math.Pow(1 - fraction, 2))
                    + (c2.Y * 3 * Math.Pow(fraction, 2) * (1 - fraction))
                    + (end.Y * Math.Pow(fraction, 3))), 0), UNLIT);
            }

            return points;
        }

        /*
        * This function treats the curve as a series of straight lines and calculates points on a line perpendicular to each point, resulting in two points THICKNESS appart. 
        * Requires THICKNESS to be set
        */
        public static VertexPositionColor[] curveToStrip(VertexPositionColor[] curve)
        {
            VertexPositionColor[] strip = new VertexPositionColor[curve.Length * 2];
            VertexPositionColor[] new1 = new VertexPositionColor[curve.Length];
            VertexPositionColor[] new2 = new VertexPositionColor[curve.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < curve.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < curve.Length-1)
                {
                    Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(curve[i].Position.X, curve[i].Position.Y);
                    Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(curve[i + 1].Position.X, curve[i + 1].Position.Y);
                    Vector2 perpPoint = perpendicularPoint(p1, p2);

                    new1[i] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(distanceToPoint(p1, perpPoint, THICKNESS / 2), 0), UNLIT);
                    new2[i] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(distanceToPoint(p1, perpPoint, -1 * THICKNESS / 2), 0), UNLIT);
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector2 p1 = new Vector2(curve[i].Position.X, curve[i].Position.Y);
                    Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(curve[i - 1].Position.X, curve[i - 1].Position.Y);
                    Vector2 perpPoint = perpendicularPoint(p1, p2);

                    new1[i] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(distanceToPoint(p1, perpPoint, -1 * THICKNESS / 2), 0), UNLIT);
                    new2[i] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(distanceToPoint(p1, perpPoint, THICKNESS / 2), 0), UNLIT);
                }
            }
```

I thought about calling the functions on the draw phase but this seems very expensive just to make a tiny curve and to draw a bigger Beziers path I imagine it worse. Since I would get a point at each frame, each function would be called to calculate the curve between points just to draw 1 curve of 3 pixels (or less).

How can I proceed? Any suggestions?

I am still a beginner on this kind of stuff!

All this I got from several sources:

[CathmullRom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915849/xna-catmullrom-curves/14916185#14916185)

[Beziers and Triangle strip](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/595843-bezier-curve-to-triangle-strip/)

Comment: Interesting question. Out of curiosity, what kind of trail will your ship leave behind (smoke, light, etc)? If it's smoke then you can deploy n amount of smoke at current position (for each frame), which can then expand over time then gradually fade, without the need of Beziers Paths or Cathmull Rom.

Comment: @user3256944 yes that is one of the alternatives I've been thinking about. But I want this to work, if after sometime it doesn't I'll try some other effect like the smoke effect you suggested that shouldn't be that hard to make. I also want to learn how to use the trianglestrips effectively with beziers and cathmull rom :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imagehosting.cz/images/trails.gif

I will just briefly explain how this works:

It is function that receives position, it is called each time you want add next segment of trail.

When function is called it adds two vertices on position, look at tangent vector from previous step, creates normal vector to current position and place vertices along that normal according to trail width.

Next it looks to at previous two vertexes and align them according to average of current and previous tangent, creating trapezoid.

I suggest to leave calculation of fading on GPU (effectively using approach of GPU particles).

If you know velocity vector of object when you are calling update of trail you can use it to optimize that algorithm. Use of dynamic vertex buffer is probably without saying (just use your own vertex format that will include current time at moment when you create those vertices so you can fade it on GPU).

Comment: Do you have some example code illustrating what you mean? The gif you show is *exactly* what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be that you create a list of trails/particles, and you init that on every frame or how much you like. i will try to explain in pseudo code below. i also rotate a bit every trail, and use different size and color of smoke texture, and added a bit of ofsset +- 5 pixels on init.

```
class Trail
    position as vector2d
    duration as single
    velocity as vector2d
    fade as integer = 1
    active = true
end class

class Trails
    inherits list of Trail
    sub Init(position as vector2d, velocity as vector2d)
        // add trail to list
    end sub
    sub Update()
        for each trail in me.findAll(function(c) c.active))
            position += velocity
            fade -= .05 // or some value
        end for
        me.removeAll(function(c) not(c.active)) // remove from list when unused
    end sub
    sub Draw()
        for each trail in me.findAll(function(c) c.active))
            draw(smokeTexture, position, size, rotate, color * trail.fade)
        end for
    end sub
end class
```

by this i have achieved this effect, it's barely visible but it gives effect.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Davor, but this isn't really the effect I'm looking for since this approach works fine for straight trails but it will look chunky for curves and such.